# Match a tag only if there is a certain tag inside

Tags: xml, regex, parsing

I would like to match tag with name `test` but only if it has more than two tags with name `one` inside `importantTag`.

```
<test attribute="one">
    <unimportantTag>
        <one>text</one>
    </unimportantTag>
    <importantTag>
        <one>text</one>
        <one>text</one>
    </importantTag>
</test>
```

This one below should not be matched because it doesn't have two `one` tags in `importantTag`:

```
    <test attribute="one">
    <unimportantTag>
        <one>text</one>
    </unimportantTag>
    <importantTag>
        <one>text</one>
    </importantTag>
</test> 
</root>
```

I know that those kind of stuff shouldn't be parsed using a regex but in this case there is no other way.
Is it possible to match whole test tag using a regex. The example was simplified.

Based on the match from regex I would like to replace the `attribute="one"` to attribute `"replaced"`.

Comment: Use HTML/XML parser please. And please remove one of them from the list of tags.

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/vF9sG0/2

Comment: @Avinash Raj - Thanks a lot, I've adjusted your pattern so it works on the full file, not a simplified one. Just got one more question. Based on that decision(that this match was found) I would like to replace the attribute "one" value to something else lets say "replaced" word. Since I've seen you were using a non capturing groups is there any simple way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer that was posted by @Avinash Raj I've built an exact regex that I wanted. I am final posting solution,  maybe someone will find it useful.

```
Search pattern:
(?s)(test)([^<>]*?)(attribute="one")(([^<>]*?)(?:(?!<\/test>).)*<importantTag>(?:(?!<\/test>|<\/importantTag>).)*<one>[^<>]*<\/one>[^<>]*<one>[^<>]*<\/one>(?:(?!<\/test>|<\/importantTag>).)*<\/importantTag>(?:(?!<\/test>).)*)<\/test>

Replace pattern:
$1$2attribute="replaced"$4>$5</test>
```

http://regex101.com/r/wU2pT9/1

Answer (score 0):

** Modified **
try this pattern

```
<test(?=(?:[^<]|<(?!\/test>))*<importantTag>(?=(?:(?:[^<]|<(?!\/test>))*<one>[^<]*<\/one>){2}))(?:[^<]|<(?!\/test>))*<\/test>
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/24)

Comment: @vks, you're right, modified my pattern above, thanks for pointing it out